# Compare two java List and add elements to final list?

Tags: java

I have two list with same type of object now what i am trying to do compare both list and create final list with these restrictions

- `dbRecord` list's all records should be available in final list
- If both list's Object's `labelName` are same then update the object of `dbrecord` list from the `userRecord` List.
- If any extra record found in `userRecord` list(Compare with `labelName` of `dbRecord`'s list object) it should be added into final list.

I tried with this code ,but issue is that it is not adding, any extra object found in `userRecord` list to final list

```
List<Labels> dbRecord = roleRecord.getLabels();
List<Labels> userRecord = role.getLabels();
List<Labels> updatedLables = new ArrayList<>();
boolean recordFound = false;
            for (Labels labels : dbRecord) {
                innerloop: for (Labels innerLabels : userRecord) {
                    if (StringUtils.compare(labels.getLabelName().replaceAll("\\s+", "").toLowerCase(),
                            innerLabels.getLabelName().replaceAll("\\s+", "").toLowerCase()) == 0) {
                        recordFound = true;
                        labels.setAccess(innerLabels.getAccess());
                        labels.setMatch(innerLabels.getMatch());
                        updatedLables.add(labels);
                    }
                    if (recordFound) {
                        break innerloop;
                    }
                }
                if (!recordFound) {
                    updatedLables.add(labels);
                }
                recordFound = false;
            }
```

What logic i am missing in this code?

**EDIT 1-**

Suppose `dbRecord` have LabelName like `Ram,Sita,Lakshman`

And `userRecord` have `LabelName` like `Ram,Sita,Krishna`

So Final List should have record `Ram,Sita,Lakshman,Krishna`

**EDIT 2-**

I am able to do this with the help of this code,Not perfect code but working as per my scenario,Other people can give proper code example.

```
boolean recordFound = false;
            for (Labels labels : dbRecord) {
                innerloop: for (Labels innerLabels : userRecord) {
                    if (StringUtils.compare(labels.getLabelName().replaceAll("\\s+", "").toLowerCase(),
                            innerLabels.getLabelName().replaceAll("\\s+", "").toLowerCase()) == 0) {
                        recordFound = true;
                        labels.setAccess(innerLabels.getAccess());
                        labels.setMatch(innerLabels.getMatch());
                        updatedLables.add(labels);
                    }
                    if (recordFound) {
                        break innerloop;
                    }
                }
                if (!recordFound) {
                    updatedLables.add(labels);
                }
                recordFound = false;
            }
            userRecord.removeAll(dbRecord);
            for(Labels labels :userRecord)
            updatedLables.add(labels);
```

FYI,I have implemented these methods in my class.

```
   @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "labelName : " + this.labelName;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return (obj instanceof Labels) && this.labelName.equals(((Labels)obj).getLabelName());
    }
     @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(labelName);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does something like this suits your needs ?

```
List<Labels> dbRecord = roleRecord.getLabels();
        List<Labels> userRecord = role.getLabels();

        Map<String, Labels> labelsByName = dbRecord.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(this::getCorrectedLabelName, i -> i));

        userRecord.stream()
            .filter(label -> labelsByName.containsKey(getCorrectedLabelName(label)))
            .forEach(label -> labelsByName.put(getCorrectedLabelName(label), label));

        Collection<Labels> updatedLabels = labelsByName.values();
```

with

```
private String getCorrectedLabelName(Labels label) {
        return label.getLabelName().replaceAll("\\s+", "").toLowerCase();
    }
```

First you create a map of labels by name using the `dbRecord` list. Then you can easily find the ones from `userRecord` that match the names, and for each of them you replace the labels in the map.

In the end you collect the map values !

PS: This is all assuming `Labels` do not have same names !

Hope this helps

--- EDIT

```
 List<Labels> dbRecord = roleRecord.getLabels();
        List<Labels> userRecord = role.getLabels();

        // create Map from dbRecord
        Map<String, Labels> labelsByName = dbRecord.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(this::getCorrectedLabelName, i -> i));

        userRecord
            // for each of userRecord
            .forEach(userRecordLabel -> {
                // if in dbRecord, update dbRecord labels
                if(labelsByName.containsKey(getCorrectedLabelName(userRecordLabel))){
                    Labels dbRecordLabel = labelsByName.get(getCorrectedLabelName(userRecordLabel));
                    dbRecordLabel.setAccess(userRecordLabel.getAccess());
                    dbRecordLabel.setMatch(userRecordLabel.getMatch());

                    labelsByName.put(getCorrectedLabelName(userRecordLabel), dbRecordLabel);

                }else{// if not then add to map
                    labelsByName.put(getCorrectedLabelName(userRecordLabel), userRecordLabel);
                }
            });

        // final complete list
        Collection<Labels> updatedLabels = labelsByName.values();
```

Here is the full corrected code that should work or you !

Comment: Sorry this Solution not work for me,in my case both List's Label class can contain same as well ,that why in my code i am checking if(name) equal update few fields and add in Final List

Comment: @A Le Dref
 I added more details about requirement.

Comment: @Sudobh Joshi what I meant saying that names should be unique is that in my code if userRecord contains same name as dbRecord then it will use the one from userRecord. Seeing your full requirements I feel like my code is doing the right job. In the last foreach my code just update label info with wanted field update. I’ll take time to update the code in the morning :)

Comment: @SubodhJoshi Did my code did the trick ? I think talking about performance it is much beter as you iterate only over userRecord list and only once compared to a lot of time before